# Setting up Stripe payment gateway

Tags: stripe

Which url do you use: `api.stripe.com` or `api.stripe.com/v3`?

I'm wondering why - even though it works fine - I have this url because I can't find any reference to /v3 in the Stripe documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its just an example used to set the url to avoid validation error. The stripe extensions uses correct api version and url while handshaking or communicating with Stripe gateway.

Comment: do you mean this URL is of no use here and the right URL is set inside the extension?

Comment: yes i believe so, since the extension uses stripe library

Comment: ok thanks Predeep, I was worrying for nothing then, thinking I should check to update or not this setting.